# CSS3 Animation and Transitions in SVG files only works in Google Chrome (not even Safari)

Tags: google-chrome, css, svg, css-transitions, css-animations

I am working on an small SVG animation (SVG downloaded from [here](http://thenounproject.com/noun/radar/#icon-No793)). I managed to get it working just fine in Google Chrome (version 21.0.1180.89 m), but not in any other browser (Including Safari - which I find weird since both are using Webkit). I am using CSS3 for animation. Below is the code - any help on this is most appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="radar" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 300 300" enable-background="new 0 0 300 300" xml:space="preserve">

<style>
#signal{
  position:absolute;
  left:150px;
  top:150px;

  transform-origin:150px 150px;
  -webkit-transform-origin:150px 150px;
  -moz-transform-origin:150px 150px;
  -o-transform-origin:150px 150px;

  animation:signal 4s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:signal 4s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:signal 4s linear infinite;
  -o-animation:signal 4s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes signal{
  from  {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to    {transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes signal{
  from  {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to    {-webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}

@-moz-keyframes signal{
  from  {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to    {-moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}

@-o-keyframes signal{
  from  {-o-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to    {-o-transform: rotate(-360deg);}
}

.planet{
  position:absolute;
  left:150px;
  top:150px;
  padding:20px;

  transform-origin:150px 150px;
  -webkit-transform-origin:150px 150px;
  -moz-transform-origin:150px 150px;
  -o-transform-origin:150px 150px;

  transition-duration:10s;
  -webkit-transition-duration:10s;
  -moz-transition-duration:10s;
  -o-transition-duration:10s;

  transition-property:width, height, transform;
  -webkit-transition-property:width, height, transform;
  -moz-transition-property:width, height, transform;
  -o-transition-property:width, height, transform;
  }

.planet:hover{
  transform:rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(360deg);

  transition-duration:2s;
  -webkit-transition-duration:2s;
  -moz-transition-duration:2s;
  -o-transition-duration:2s;
}
</style>
    <circle class="planet" fill="#000" cx="174.1" cy="58.092" r="7.881"/>
    <circle class="planet" fill="#000" cx="130.281" cy="112.11" r="6.723"/>
    <circle class="planet" fill="#000" cx="60.732" cy="99.822" r="12.285"/>

    <path fill="#000" d="M150,0C67.157,0,0,67.157,0,150s67.157,150,150,150s150-67.157,150-150S232.843,0,150,0z M278.968,147.334
    H226.37c-1.373-39.98-33.434-72.152-73.37-73.696V21.037c33.334,0.755,64.561,14.09,88.217,37.747
    C264.952,82.519,278.294,113.875,278.968,147.334z M147,147.334H79.63c1.371-36.61,30.803-66.154,67.37-67.695V147.334z
     M147,153.334v67.027c-36.345-1.532-65.652-30.725-67.353-67.027H147z M153,153.334h67.353c-1.7,36.303-31.007,65.495-67.353,67.027
    V153.334z M153,147.334V79.639c36.567,1.542,65.998,31.085,67.37,67.695H153z M58.783,58.783
    C82.439,35.127,113.666,21.792,147,21.037v52.602c-39.937,1.544-71.997,33.715-73.37,73.696H21.032
    C21.707,113.875,35.048,82.519,58.783,58.783z M21.043,153.334h52.604c1.704,39.671,33.638,71.492,73.353,73.027v52.603
    c-33.334-0.756-64.561-14.091-88.217-37.747C35.206,217.639,21.88,186.542,21.043,153.334z M241.217,241.217
    c-23.656,23.656-54.883,36.991-88.217,37.747v-52.603c39.715-1.535,71.648-33.356,73.354-73.027h52.604
    C278.12,186.542,264.795,217.639,241.217,241.217z"/>

    <path id="signal" fill="#000" d="M149.444,159.059c-2.175,0-4.351-0.83-6.01-2.489c-3.319-3.319-3.32-8.701,0-12.021l73.721-73.727
    c3.32-3.319,8.702-3.32,12.021,0c3.32,3.319,3.32,8.701,0.001,12.021l-73.721,73.727
    C153.795,158.229,151.62,159.059,149.444,159.059z"/>
</svg>
```

Thank you,
Ian

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Seems like it's an issue to do with browsers other than Chrome not supporting all CSS animation in SVG files...

Comment: Yes, CSS animation on SVG elements is just beginning to be supported, but your animation is quite straightforward to implement in js or SMIL (not supported by IE9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the bleeding edge currently, Chrome 21 was released on August 29, 2012. Firefox 16 which will be coming out on October 9th, 2012 supports this. I imagine Safari will support it at some point but it's on a lower frequency release schedule than Firefox/Chrome.